# Can i update libpqxx, can i upgrade or do i need to flash my computer to reinstall a newer version?

Tags: c++, gcc, libpq, libpqxx

I have checked out and built version 6.4 of libpqxx from https://github.com/jtv/libpqxx, how can i now install versoin 7.1.1? Can i remove the current version and how?
Can i have both versions installed, and how do i specify which one when linking in a compiler command?

I tried to read the docs, but could not get any info i could use.

Or, do i need to flasch my BeagleBoneBlack and reinstall everything from scratch?

Comment: Install in different locations (based on the version number). Provide the proper include and library flags (`-I`, `-L` and `-l`) to find the specific version you want to use.

Comment: my current libpqxx.a and libpqxx.la resides in /usr/local/lib    , how do i specify a new directory to put new vesrion of libpqxx in when executing .configure/make/make install. Is the install location defined in the configure-part/file and I need to change that, or can i specify it using command line when executing "make"?

Comment: So, by the way: If I delete libpqxx and libpqxx.a from /usr/local/lib i can "reinstall" libpqxx with .configure/make/make install with version 7.1.1 and problem is solved ? :D (Because they are static libraries, and therefore have no dependencies?)